# Copyright restriction in other countries

Tags: copyright

Amazon.com sometimes refuses to sell me audiobooks. The message is as follows:

[image]

I don't understand how a copyright can be enforced in *other countries*. Surely copyright holds for a specific country where it is registered, and has no enforceable jurisdiction in others. Is this type of copyright restriction valid? Under what law?

I can buy the digital text, so this issue is with the copyright for the audio only.

Comment: Probably their legal department decided that they don't know how exactly to handle this, and so their verdict was don't take any risks by selling stuff into regions where the situation is unclear. There could also be an agreement between Amazon and the copyright holder to not sell into specific regions. Perhaps the copyright holder has an exclusive agreement with another agent.

Comment: @tripleee that sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copyright is mutually recognised in most countries

Of the 206 sovereign states in the world 178 are signatories to the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) which gives domestic copyright protection to works produced in other member states.

Book publishing has traditionally been regional - one company pays the author for the rights in Europe, another in North America and so on. Amazon does not have distribution rights to this audiobook where you are. Someone else may or the author may still hold those rights personally. Audio and text books are different copyright works and can have different arrangements.

Comment: Wouldn't that would mean that the conditions are equal across the Berne Convention countries? The audiobook can presumably be bought in some country, if it's on Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

Two bases in law can think of besides Amazon just being cautious:

- As mentioned by tripleee's comment, there could be a specific agreement between Amazon and the copyright holder. Amazon needs consent of the copyright holder because one of the rights granted in copyright law is the right of distribution.
- Copyright law is on a per-country basis, additionally the international Berne Convention requires foreign works be treated equally to domestic works (rule of the shorter term being the major exception).  For example, if I as a Canadian publish an original work, I can not only assert my rights in Canadian courts under Canadian law, but I could theoretically also assert my rights in French courts under French copyright law.